# Error in node application - "Cannot read properties of undefined"

Tags: node.js, sails.js, node-modules

I downloaded my sails project from github which I created few years ago. When I try to run the sails.js project using "sails lift" than the following error comes up.

[image]

PS: I am new to Sails.js

Comment: Can you put your code or line where you got error ?